# Obtain servlet user credentials (password) after login, e.g. from j_security_check

Tags: authentication, servlets, jetty

I need to access the user's password in a Jetty application after authentication, and can't figure out how.

I am migrating a set of web pages away from basic authentication in an embedded Jetty servlet application. I cannot, however, completely remove basic authentication from all of the services that these pages call, so I need to forward the user credentials in some cases, which means storing and later retrieving the user's password.

I introduced forms authentication to the root context via the standard markup in `web.xml`, which works fine but I can find no way of getting the user credentials programatically.  As far as I can tell there is no way to place a `Filter` on `j_security_check` to intercept and store the form parameters in the session state. Jetty provides all the user credentials in the session state but this is in a container-specific key and although the application is currently tied to Jetty I would strongly prefer a container-agnostic solution.  Here are some specific questions that I've tried to formulate after going down a number of seemingly dead-end streets:

1. How can I obtain the user's password after login?  Even if I moved the services away from basic authentication I would still need to perform some secondary action such as obtaining a token, in which case I would still need their credentials under my control for a brief period.
2. Assuming I can't obtain the user's password directly, perhaps I can leverage something in the container to store the credentials.  I can implement my own `LoginService` that wraps the actual implementation, but that class does not have access to the `HttpSession` or `Request` objects.  Where is the proper place to do this?
3. If I need to implement a custom login solution, I'm not quite sure where to start...the `FormAuthenticator` has a lot of complicated session state management that I would like to preserve and not reproduce willy-nilly, and I would still prefer to defer to the container standard as much as possible.  Is there some standard method for extending or overriding the `j_security_check` logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found one solution, for anyone else attempting similar - and I've found quite a few other posts from confused devs, and some badly hacked together workarounds.  I believe this one is correct, although you must do the URL filtering yourself and it leaves open the question as to why this is possible, if indeed `j_security_check` should be exempt from this type of interception for security reasons, as is claimed many places online.  Perhaps I am merely exploiting an unknown gap in the Jetty security measures, so I will leave this question open for a while to see if there is a more robust or explicit solution.

`ServletRequestListener` allows you to latch onto the `j_security_check` post request before it is fully initialized.  There you can get both the form parameters and the session object.  So in the end it was just a matter of exhausting every possible servlet-related class in Jetty until I found one that would give me access to the `j_security_check` request.  Some code:

```java
public class PreAuthenticationRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    public static final String USERNAME_KEY = "USERNAME";
    public static final String PASSWORD_KEY = "PASSWORD";

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {

    }

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)sre.getServletRequest();
        if (request.getRequestURI().contains("j_security_check")) {
            final String username = request.getParameter("j_username");
            final String password = request.getParameter("j_password");

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute(USERNAME_KEY, username);
            session.setAttribute(PASSWORD_KEY, password);
        }
    }
}
```